# Resources on how to typeset fonts

Tags: fonts, typesetting, typeset

I would like to get into the weeds of typesetting, but I do struggle finding any resources which would explain to me how the digital typesetting works.

Can you please give me some leads on to how to typeset fonts?

Maybe to clarify - I am asking more about the whole kerning, spacing, and other technical aspects of typesetting. The idea is to just learn a thing or two about it, possibly write a toy project.

I tried to google some tutorials for it and apart from Knuth's TeXbook there seem to be little to no resources (possibly looking for wrong keywords).

Comment: Your question is out of scope here. A better forum for asking would be https://typedrawers.com/.